# Why does water boil when vapour pressure is equivalent to atmospheric pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water, phase-transition

I'm struggling to understand why water would suddenly evaporate in a vacuum. Does the water already posses enough energy to boil when the ambient pressure is zero?

Comment: Yes.  The energy to boil the water comes from the water itself.  As a consequence, the water temperature drops as it boils in a vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

We normally associate boiling with bubbles (filled with water vapor) which form and rise to the surface.  For the bubbles to grow, the pressure inside must be slightly greater than the ambient pressure.